# matplotlibで作成したグラフをtkinterに表示させ、そのx軸、y軸をボタンで範囲を変更できるようにしたい

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

下記のコードでグラフを描写させることができたのですが、その後にx軸やy軸の範囲を可変にする方法を調べても見つけることができなかったので、ご教授願います。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

def file_select():
    idir = r'C:\Users'
    file_path1 = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=idir)
    input_box.insert(tk.END, file_path1)

    data = np.loadtxt(file_path1, comments="*")
    ax.plot(data[:, 0], np.log10(data[:, 1] * data[:, 2]), label="Si", linewidth=0.4)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

plt.title("sample")  # グラフのタイトル
plt.xlabel(r"x")  # x軸の名前
plt.ylabel("y")  # y軸の名前
plt.xlim(20, 70)  # x軸の範囲
plt.ylim(0, 25)  # y軸の範囲
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.85), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=1, fontsize=12)

input_box = tk.Entry(width=40)
input_box.place(x=10, y=100)
input_box.pack()

# ボタン1
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="参照", command=file_select)
btn1.pack()
# ボタン2
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="終了", command=lambda: root.quit())
btn2.pack()

root.withdraw()
root.update()
root.deiconify()
root.mainloop()
```

metroplisさん、kunifさんありがとうございます。ここから自分でも考えてみます。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [【matplotlib】グラフをtkinterの画面に埋め込む方法【Python】](https://www.python-beginners.com/entry/20210720/1626710254), [Pythonでグラフ（Matplotlib）を表示して動的に変更する](https://water2litter.net/rum/post/python_tkinter_matplotlib/), [MatplotlibでリアルタイムグラフのX軸、Y軸を動作中に変更する](https://qiita.com/Nomisugi/items/ecb7385f2562c0a6b953), [【python】tkinterを使ってPID制御を簡単に試せるアプリを作ってみた](https://www.stjun.com/entry/2020/01/16/225754)

Answer (score 1):

ボタンではなく [matplotlib.widgets.RangeSlide](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.RangeSlider) を使ってみました。

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.widgets import RangeSlider
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from functools import partial

def plot_data(ax):
    # select data file
    idir = r'C:\Users'
    file_path1 = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=idir)
    input_box.insert(tk.END, file_path1)

    # import data and plot
    data = np.loadtxt(file_path1, comments='*')
    ax.plot(
      data[:, 0], np.log10(data[:, 1] * data[:, 2]),
      label='Si', linewidth=0.4)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()

    # add range slider to x-axis
    slx = plt.axes([0.2, 0.07, 0.7, 0.03])
    x_slider = RangeSlider(
        ax=slx, label='', valmin=20, valmax=70,
        valinit=(20, 70), valstep=1)
    
    # add range slider to y-axis
    sly = plt.axes([0.08, 0.2, 0.025, 0.68])
    y_slider = RangeSlider(
        ax=sly, label='', valmin=0, valmax=25,
        valinit=(0, 25), valstep=1, orientation='vertical')

    # callback function when moving slider
    def update(val):
        ax.set_xlim(*(x_slider.val))
        ax.set_ylim(*(y_slider.val))
        canvas.draw()

    x_slider.on_changed(update)
    y_slider.on_changed(update)

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)

    plt.title('sample')  # グラフのタイトル
    plt.xlabel('x')  # x軸の名前
    plt.ylabel('y')  # y軸の名前
    plt.xlim(20, 70)  # x軸の範囲
    plt.ylim(0, 25)  # y軸の範囲
    plt.legend(
      bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.85), loc='upper left',
      borderaxespad=1, fontsize=12)

    input_box = tk.Entry(width=40)
    input_box.place(x=10, y=100)
    input_box.pack()

    # ボタン1
    btn1 = tk.Button(
      root, text='参照', command=partial(plot_data, ax))
    btn1.pack()

    # ボタン2
    btn2 = tk.Button(
      root, text='終了', command=lambda: root.quit())
    btn2.pack()

    root.withdraw()
    root.update()
    root.deiconify()
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: screen capture]